# Divs insist on being larger than their content

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontally scrolling website for my photography portfolio, so to make it easier for people to navigate I made it possible to have the website scroll horizontally when the user scrolls vertically. However, since I did this the divs holding each image INSIST on being a fixed width and not conforming to the width of the images they contain. I'm relatively inexperienced with coding so any help getting the divs to match the width of their images would be appreciated.

[Here is my html and css](https://jsfiddle.net/j_matta_/c2pdngq8/#&togetherjs=gqrmfUJQ4o)

```
<div class="main-content">
<div class="banner-01 post">
<img src="http://jmatta.com/images/pix/Main/frankell.jpg">
</div>
<div class="banner-02 post">
<img src="http://jmatta.com/images/pix/Main/HMR17.jpg">
</div>
<div class="banner-03 post">
<img src="http://jmatta.com/images/pix/Main/Banes16.jpg">
</div>
<div class="banner-04 post">
<img src="http://jmatta.com/images/pix/Main/scott5.jpg">
</div>
</div>

body {
background: white;
color: black;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 24px;
}

.main-content{
position:absolute;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
top: 50px;
left:250px;
width:700px;
max-height:1150px;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-700px);
transform-origin:right top;
}

.main-content div{
transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(700px);
transform-origin: right top;
display: inline-block;
}

.main-content img{
max-height: 89vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you rotated parents of the images, it is the height of divs that appears not to follow the height of the contained images. I am not sure why did you rotate the `main-content`. I removed all the rotations and transformations (are they necessary for some reason?) and simplified the whole code in general. `img` and `div` now have the same size. If you need spacing between images, just add side margin to the image.

I believe this is the solution you are looking for:
[code](https://codepen.io/tonkec/pen/PXGaXQ)